# Perform a diff on 2 texts, using only part of each line in the texts

Tags: python, algorithm, diff

I have two texts.

```
T0 ID A
T1 ID B
T2 ID C
T4 ID D
```

and

```
T5 ID A
T6 ID E
T7 ID F
T8 ID D
```

I really am only interested in comparing the differences in the sequence of ID's, the letters. But I want to keep the first part of each element in the output, so I can use it for other analysis later, ie the output would look something like this

```
@-1,2 +1,2
-T2 ID B
-T3 ID C
+T6 ID E
+T7 ID F
```

What is the best way to do this sort of diff? Ideally with the difflib python library.

Also, say instead of 2 texts, I have 2 lists of objects, each with 2 attributes (object.t returns T1, object.ID returns B), and I want to perform the diff on the lists of objects only with respect to their ID attribute. I could I perform such an operation? Maybe this should be a different question.

Thanks

Comment: Your list structure is not clear.  How are you representing them in Python?

Comment: Sorry it was sort of ambiguous, Lets just use a very simple example of plain text. I added an "Also" to the question to cover comparing lists of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subclass of `str` that hashes and compares as if it consisted only of its ID:

```
import re

class IdString(str):
    """A string that hashes and compares on its id.

        >>> hash(IdString('XXX ID A XXX')) == hash('A')
        True
        >>> hash(IdString('XXX ID abc XXX')) == hash('abc')
        True
        >>> IdString('XXX ID A XXX') == IdString('YYY ID A YYY')
        True
        >>> IdString('XXX ID A XXX') == IdString('XXX ID B XXX')
        False

    """
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        self = super(IdString, cls).__new__(cls, *args)
        m = re.search(r'\bID (\w+)', self)
        self.id = m.group(1)
        return self

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.id != other.id
```

Then you can turn your ordinary strings into `IdString` objects and pass those to `difflib`, like this:

```
from difflib import unified_diff

text1 = '''T0 ID A
T1 ID B
T2 ID C
T4 ID D
'''

text2 = '''T5 ID A
T6 ID E
T7 ID F
T8 ID D
'''

print(''.join(unified_diff(map(IdString, text1.splitlines(True)),
                           map(IdString, text2.splitlines(True)),
                           n=0)))
```

which produces very nearly the output you want:

```
--- 
+++ 
@@ -2,2 +2,2 @@
-T1 ID B
-T2 ID C
+T6 ID E
+T7 ID F
```

(The example in your question says `@-1,2 +1,2` but I couldn't reproduce that exactly because I don't know what style of diff that is, and line numbers start at 1 in diff output.)